# Votos contrários aparentemente sem razão

Tags: debate, votação, voto-contra

Há alguns dias atrás [uma pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/608/qual-a-diferenca-entre-codigo-client-side-e-server-side-em-desenvolvimento-web/) inicialmente marcada para fechamento (pela simplicidade, suponho) gerou um fenômeno estranho: praticamente toda resposta era recebida por múltiplos votos contrários, apesar de não haver nada errado com elas (a minha por exemplo está atualmente com +6/-4). Hoje [outra pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1109/onde-devo-colocar-um-codigo-javascript-em-um-documento-html) - que por sinal também foi marcada para fechamento (um usuário acreditou que ela era subjetiva - incorretamente IMHO, como pode se ver pelas respostas) começou a apresentar o mesmo fenômeno.

Será que os usuários não estão sabendo como funciona o voto? Que não é pra votar negativo somente por não concordar com alguma coisa (pergunta ou resposta), mas sim quando o post não acrescentar nada ou tiver problemas? Ou seria uma questão de má-fé e, nesse caso, qual a melhor forma de proceder? (sinalizar, trazer à discussão no meta, outra coisa...)

Comment: Definitivamente estão votando por opinião, o que só é válido no meta.

Comment: @BrunoLM Na verdade é impossível controlar por que estão votando, e cada um tem liberdade de votar pelo motivo que quiser. O que me preocupa aqui é a possibilidade de ser alguém tentando abusar do sistema, possivelmente usando múltiplas contas para isso. E isso os moderadores conseguem detectar.

Comment: Prefiro acreditar no que você está dizendo, se for um usuário abusando do sistema é bem melhor do que uma comunidade inteira votando de forma incorreta... Espero que seja isso mesmo.

Comment: Uma possibilidade seria a do ["voto contrário tático"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22771/177950) - quando um respondente vota contrário nos "concorrentes" para elevar a visibilidade de sua resposta. Não parece ser o caso aqui, mas é algo que pode vir a acontecer (e só se torna problema se se tornar "norma" *de facto*, creio que esporadicamente isso é difícil de evitar - ou mesmo detectar)

Comment: De qualquer forma, é uma prática que temos que tentar evitar, até onde possível (não muito).

Comment: Sei que a mesma pessoa a votar a negativo ou positivo com várias contas de utilizador é "apanhada" pelo sistema. Recordo-me desses cenários à uns 2 anos atrás e do [Jeff](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1/jeff-atwood) e outros terem explicado que essa malta é "apanhada"... não consigo é encontrar o tópico no META principal. Se encontrar meto aqui o link!

Comment: Depoimento: fiz uma pergunta uma vez (a pergunta cita acima antes do link) e logo após aparecer a primeira resposta o usuário recebeu 4 down votes seguidos, em muito pouco tempo (talvez uns 1~2 min.) e logo em seguida todos foram retirados e passaram para outra resposta, foi algo muito esquisito. Aparentemente tem alguém utilizando varias contas para realizar esses down votes.

Answer (score 7):

Eu acredito que possa existir uma parcela de má-fé. Eu não ia falar nada, mas já que essa situação bizarra não está acontecendo só comigo, vou descrever algo que ocorreu há dois dias [nesta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/909/como-deixar-tab-bootstrap-ativa-apos-clicar-em-paginacao/913#913):

1. **15:45** - Pergunta é feita
2. **16:41** - Respondida por um outro usuário
3. **17:00** - Respondida por mim
4. **17:02** - Minha resposta é sinalizada como "de baixa qualidade"
5. **17:11** - OP diz que vai testar minha solução
6. **17:23** - O outro usuário edita sua resposta e acrescenta de forma ligeiramente modificada a parte da minha resposta que o OP disse que ia testar.
7. **17:28** - O outro usuário comenta minha resposta assim: "Falou falou e não disse nada consistente. -1".
8. **17:32** - OP me agradece porque o código funcionou e posteriormente aceita minha resposta

Este foi um caso específico, onde a resposta certa ficou com menos votos que as demais sem motivo algum, mas em outras respostas minhas recebi de cara, em média, 2 votos negativos. É quase como se estivessem competindo para ver quem fica mais para cima.

A questão é que não é apenas uma pessoa, parece um grupinho que age de acordo mas sem se expor.

Comment: Estou vendo padrões assim acontecer. No momento estamos praticamente sem moderação (Cadê o Gabe?), mas essa festa vai acabar.

Comment: @bigown Se o Gabe não pode, acho que devias pegar no diamante dele e seguir para a frente de batalha! :)

Comment: @utluiz Observei esse teu caso em particular e fartei-me de o procurar aqui à um par de dias para trazer aqui à META. O meu motivo era o facto da tua resposta ser a resposta certa mas estar com votação de -1. _fiquei tipo ?!?!?_ (na altura não encontrei o tópico, mas fizeste bem em falar e incentivo que tu e outros falem sempre!)

Comment: @Zuul obviamente eu tenho interesse em ser moderador, mas primeiro precisamos sair do privado ;) O pessoal talvez não tenha percebido que um moderador tem disponível informações extras para descobrir esse tipo de coisa e em um site pequeno fica muito visível.

Comment: Estamos cientes da situação, e monitorá-lo ativamente. Será que adiar para Gabe para uma resposta detalhada, uma vez que eu suspeito que o Google Translate está fazendo um hash de mesmo esta curta resposta.

Comment: @Shog9 Yap, Google Translate is killing you on that one ;) _(Sim, o Tradutor da Google está-te a enganar na tradução dessa resposta!)_

Comment: @Shog9 It's ok you (and whole SE staff) post here in English.

Comment: @shog9 Feel free to count on us to help you translate anything you want. Google and other translators usually are weak in regards to portuguese. Bing sometimes seems to have better results, but usually weak too. Perhaps we could also have a tag here devoted to threads in english, where we can discuss translation and help.

Comment: Isso já aconteceu comigo várias vezes aqui - mas no SO inglês também, o que acaba tirando um pouco da vontade de contribuir, infelizmente.

Answer (score 5):

Num site "já graduado" (ou mesmo naqueles em beta público, pelo que pude observar) os usuários precisam ter `125` de reputação para votar contrário. Isso significa que nenhum usuário novo - mesmo aqueles com o bônus de associação (`100` pontos "de graça" que ajudam a eliminar as restrições de novo usuário) - pode sair votando contra como bem entender. Precisa primeiro se familiarizar com a comunidade e entender o que é aceito, o que não é.

Como os votos são anonimizados, nós usuários comuns não temos como saber com certeza o que está havendo. Pelo pouco que conheço dos usuários envolvidos, não acredito que seja um "voto tático" (i.e. uns votando contra nos outros para melhorar a colocação da sua resposta), e nem me parece tampouco um "toma-la-dá-cá" (embora confesso que no primeiro caso cheguei a agir de cabeça quente e votar contra duas respostas - [mas apenas nas que considerei menos úteis](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mecanismo_de_defesa#Racionaliza.C3.A7.C3.A3o), e estou pronto para retirá-los caso o autor elabore mais). Acrecido que quem votou não foram os mesmos que responderam, na maioria dos casos.

Se for esse o caso, creio que o problema vai "se resolver sozinho" tão logo cheguemos no beta público. Ou no mínimo isso se tornará mais esporádico. De todo modo, vamos ficar atentos pra ver se isso se repete (por exemplo, atualizando essa pergunta com os novos casos, se houver) e, se julgarmos necessário, pedir a intervenção dos moderadores (nem que seja só pra investigar).

Comment: No caso dos votos "contra" convém sempre deixar um comentário a dizer "Fui eu... por causa disto..." de forma a dar oportunidade à pessoa que respondeu de retificar ou melhorar a resposta! Idem-aspas para as perguntas!

Comment: Eu sinalizei uma resposta explicando a situação com o link para cá. Espero que quando os moderadores voltarem investiguem logo.

Answer (score 5):

A maior parte dos cenários possíveis já está salientes nas demais respostas.

Só quero acrescentar que este site é ***novissssssssimo***, está naturalmente a atrair pessoal inexperiente em questões de "trabalhar para um bem comum", pessoal de "cabeça quente" como já referido.

Eu acho que estes comportamentos são normais pois já os vivi nos vários sites que vi crescer aqui na StackExchange.

Também acho que mais cedo ou mais tarde o pessoal vai "crescer" em termos de sensibilização para o trabalho que cada um faz para cada um poder desfrutar e os votos a negativo a dada altura deixam de ser tão frequentes e começam a desaparecer!

Ao início é sempre uma questão de ver *"quem a tem maior*", mas com o passar do tempo as pessoas amadurecem e começam a entender que a qualidade e veracidade das perguntas e respostas é efetivamente o que deve servir como medida de voto.

**Nota final:**

Votar a negativo em respostas faz o utilizador perder reputação, a dada altura deixa de haver reputação para ser perdida ou deixa de valer à pena andar aqui todos os dias só para clicar na seta que aponta para baixo! Esse pessoal ou "cresce" ou farta-se e parte para outra!

---

<sup>Usei algumas palavras duras de ler, mas não quero com isto ofender ninguém. Também quero que fique claro que não estou a falar de ninguém em particular.</sup>

Answer (score 4):

Acho que o que acontece é isso:

1. O cara vê a pergunta e acha que é uma pergunta idiota por que ele considera ser fácil e simplória.
2. Ele vota contra a pergunta.
3. Ele vota para fechar a pergunta.
4. Ele vê pessoas respondendo a pergunta, fica com raivinha e já vota contra sem nem ler o texto das respostas, afinal ele julga que a pergunta nem sequer merece resposta.
5. Ele ignora, desconsidera ou não se importa com o fato de que o texto da pergunta e das respostas provavelmente será melhorado dentro de alguns minutos.

Assim, se aparecer alguém aqui perguntando algo do tipo "como declarar o método main no java?" ou "qual que é a diferença entre um compilador e um interpretador?", pode ter certeza que esse fenômeno se repetirá. E isso poderá se tornar um fenômeno perigoso quando formos para o beta público.

Um forte indício disso, tal como no comentário que fiz na sua resposta a primeira pergunta:

> "respondida 55 segs atrás", já com -2 votos. Putz, tem gente por aqui que é ninja na hora de votar contra. Vamos com calma pessoal.

Ou seja, quem votou contra o fez quando a questão tinha sido postada a pouquíssimo tempo e as respostas também, e tão logo as respostas apareciam, eles já iam lá clicar na setinha para baixo.

Não acho que seja um grupo tentando prejudicar de propósito o site, pois eles agem com questões simples enquanto estas são novas. Alguém que quisesse fazer de propósito ia ter que ficar com o site aberto, monitorando as perguntas, apenas esperando a hora em que uma pergunta de um determinado tipo aparecesse para começar a clicar nas setinhas para baixo. Além disso, se essas pessoas quisessem prejudicar o site, fariam isso com perguntas mais fortes.

O que me parece ser é que há um grupo de pessoas um tanto elitistas aqui, que está apenas exagerando na hora de julgar se o nível das perguntas é bom ou não, sendo intolerante com perguntas de iniciantes e vingativo com quem responde estas perguntas.

Comment: Só um porém: a pergunta de hoje ninguém votou contra (só as respostas têm votos contra).

Comment: @bfavaretto Não tem voto contra, mas tem 2 votos para fechar, algo que é ainda pior.

Comment: O que descreves é possível, mas essa última parte sobre "pessoal elitista" não sei se concordo! Mas pessoalmente penso que algumas das coisas da página de ajuda tem que ser estabelecidas para que cada um saiba como agir perante cada cenário, e de certa forma permitir ao moderadores a tomada de ação em conformidade com aquilo que é a regra do site...

Comment: ...Pessoalmente, ainda não votei a negativo e já estou sem mandar fechar nada até que o assunto da página de ajuda esteja resolvido! Isto no seguimento desta [resposta do @bigown](http://meta.br.stackoverflow.com/questions/333/pergunta-a-procura-de-opinioes-reaberta) onde ficou claro o que acabei de dizer (de notar que concordo em pleno com a resposta!).