# Por que existe preconceito em perguntar e responder a própria pergunta?

Tags: debate

Nos comentários de uma Q&A que fiz:

[image: comentarios]

<sup>* Aceitei a resposta antes do talles responder, depois de ~3 dias.</sup>

E recebi um downvote na minha pergunta e resposta que funciona melhor que a outra resposta.

Não é a primeira vez que eu recebo downvotes por isso.

As pessoas não estão entendendo o que é Stack Overflow.

A questão é: o que pode ser feito para diminuir esse comportamento, downvotes por preconceito ou seja lá o que for isso?

Comment: Esclarecimento: votei a favor desta pergunta porque acho que precisamos debater mais este assunto, mas não concordo com a sua opinião.

Comment: Reavivando esta questão de responder a propria pergunta ou não, eu fico querendo saber se já estamos vivendo uma nova fase no SOpt, onde é sábio se auto responder, ou não. As vezes (o que é meu caso agora) fazemos uma pergunta e durante os comentários acabamos construindo uma resposta que pode vir a ser o que acreditamos ser certo, e algumas vezes pode até ser uma melhor resposta do que a que foi dada. Eu mesmo já me queixei de pessoas que usam nossa resposta para amadurecer a própria sem cita-la, mas acho certo (mantendo a autoria) resumir respostas e condensar em uma nova e melhor.

Answer (score 8):

Isso já está sendo discutido [nessa outra pergunta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/37/respondi-minha-propria-pergunta-fiz-algo-errado). Vou reiterar o que disse na [minha resposta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/37/respondi-minha-propria-pergunta-fiz-algo-errado/168#168):

> Por isso minha opinião é de que perguntar algo que já se sabe e responder direto **não é "errado", mas foge do interesse da comunidade nesse primeiro momento**. Fazer isso de vez em quando - principalmente se se tratar de suas próprias perguntas (e não algo aleatoriamente escolhido pra se traduzir do SO em inglês) - não representa um problema, e a frequência com que isso ocorre tende a aumentar com o tempo (e à medida que vemos outras pessoas fazendo isso). Só peço pra termos cuidado para não exagerar, ou "destruiremos nosso próprio ecossistema"...

Notei que uma parcela significativa das suas perguntas contém auto-respostas, o que mostra que elas não foram feitas porque você tinha uma dúvida, mas simplesmente para "documentar" um conhecimento que você já tem (o fato de você ter etiqueta e levar a resposta dos outros em consideração é irrelevante - o problema está na artificialidade da pergunta). Ora, todos nós temos conhecimentos que podem ser documentados também, e eu seria um tremendo hipócrita se negasse que estou com a mão coçando pra começar a adicionar um monte de perguntas desse tipo também. O "X" da questão é: **agora é a hora certa pra se fazer isso?**

Eu sou da opinião que não, e venho me abstendo de perguntar algo que já sei num esforço para ajudar a criar uma comunidade "saudável". Outros podem ter opinião diferente, mas suspeito que muitos pensem como eu (ex.: eu não voto contrário nesse tipo de pergunta, apenas me abstenho de votar; não posso adivinhar por que os outros estão votando contra suas perguntas, mas pode ter a ver com isso).

Agora, se ficar determinado que esse tipo de pergunta é ok nesse momento, *de jus* ou *de facto*, então eu vou parar de esquentar a cabeça com isso e começar a agir de forma semelhante... (**Atualização:** segundo o @Gabe, [não há problemas nisso](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/422/responder-sua-propria-pergunta), então se a comunidade estiver de acordo, eu retiro minhas objeções e vamos ver no que dá...)

Comment: Acredito que todas perguntas que selecionei foram as que um dia postei no SO ou que eu já tive. A pergunta é artificial só porque eu sei a resposta? Todas ou quase todas que escolhi tem milhares de visualizações, como isso não seria de beneficio para outros? E mesmo que eu tenha respondido minha pergunta, ainda é possivel que outras pessoas respondam ela também, incluindo alternativas ou até mesmo um modo melhor. O _Answer Ratio_ que precisamos é 2.5, mas quase ninguém responde as perguntas que fiz e respondi e em alguns casos, como esse, eu ainda ganho downvote. Só consigo ver isso como birra

Comment: Concordo 100%. Eu também queria postar esse tipo de conteúdo, e resolvi não fazer isso porque neste momento está mesmo parecendo artificial - especialmente quando são várias perguntas do mesmo usuário.

Comment: @Bruno Será que as pessoas não estão deixando de responder justamente porque estão achando artificial?

Comment: [Exemplo](http://br.stackoverflow.com/q/834/40) Eu sabia a resposta, mas não respondi. Só teve uma resposta, mas foi muito boa.

Comment: @BrunoLM como falei, não tenho como adivinhar por que os outros estão dando downvote. Pode ser "birra", pode não ser. Eu não uso voto contrário para expressar opinião fora do meta, e se tem gente fazendo isso [é realmente um problema a ser discutido e trabalhado](http://meta.br.stackoverflow.com/questions/344/votos-contrarios-aparentemente-sem-razao).

Comment: @bfavaretto E muitas delas, não são grandes questões. Não me importaria de algo que é sensacional, que só no SO você poderia ver algo tão legal. Estou até pensando em colocar algo assim para testar o que as pessoas pensam quando o conteúdo não é original mas é *great*.

Answer (score 8):

Já disse ao BrunoLM e vou dizer mais uma vez, popularidade não é parâmetro para discutir qualidade. Enquanto houver essa insistência, vou considerar que não há entendimento do que é o SO.

Não posso falar por quem deu downvote na resposta, mas posso dizer que é no mínimo compreensível que as pessoas se irritem quando há aceitação da sua própria questão quando a outra está mais elaborada (não necessariamente mais correta), aparentemente foi feita pelo próprio autor da resposta e foi mais votada. Não estou dizendo que não pode trazer a resposta do SO como foi feito neste caso e que não pode aceitar a sua própria resposta mesmo a outra sendo mais votada, claro que pode, mas pode trazer consequências e elas devem ser aceitas também.

Se fosse o caso de alegar fraude ou vandalismo no sistema, de um lado ou de outro, algo teria que ser feito. Voto de retaliação por exemplo é muito pior, porque aí o voto não leva em consideração o conteúdo.

Particularmente não costumo votar como punição, mas alguém pode se sentir tentado a fazê-lo pra compensar um voto up mal dado, por exemplo. Voto para destacar ou diminuir a importância de conteúdo relevante ou fraco, respectivamente. Por isso mesmo costumo dar down apenas em perguntas (claro que o fato de não ter custo, ajuda também :) ). Mas esse é o **meu** pensamento. Ninguém é obrigado seguir esse critério.

Respostas melhores são facilmente destacadas com votos positivos nas demais. Em perguntas isso se torna um pouco mais difícil, o voto negativo se torna mais importante para diferenciar o que é melhor do que é apenas útil.

O voto é consciência de cada um. Se o conteúdo está sendo analisado e tem um motivo para o voto, ok. O critério não é igual pra todo mundo. O que é bom para um é ruim para outro. Existem algumas ideias do que é elegante fazer na votação, mas não uma regra obrigatória.

Não aconteceu neste caso, mas o BrunoLM já demonstrou em outras ocasiões que confunde o que é não gostar de um conteúdo (criteriosamente analisado com a consciência individual) e não ser adequado para o site. No primeiro as pessoas simplesmente votam, no segundo elas votam para fechar. Que eu me lembre nunca ninguém votou para fechar questões do BrunoLM, apenas consideram que o conteúdo não merece destaque. Eu devo ter votando negativamente em pelo menos duas *perguntas* dele que considerei que não estavam ajudando muito o site, mas não votei para fechar.

Apesar do BrunoLM se considerar perseguido, **me parece** que as pessoas estão considerando existir uma atitude individualista e não comunitária. E estão agindo para indicar isso ativamente.

Neste caso específico, não vi má fé, pelo contrário, vi uma atitude tentando uma melhoria na comunidade. Não estou entrando na questão se concordo ou não, apenas respondendo a pergunta. Não vi preconceito algum. Hoje está muito na moda achar que qualquer discordância seja preconceito.

Me *pareceu* que está querendo pegar carona [nesta pergunta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/344/votos-contrarios-aparentemente-sem-razao), e são casos completamente diferentes. A comunidade sinalizou que não aceita aquele tipo de comportamento, vamos ver o que as pessoas acham desse caso de voto de boa fé que desagradou o autor.

Answer (score 6):

"As pessoas não estão entendendo o que é Stack Overflow.
A questão é: o que pode ser feito para diminuir esse comportamento, downvotes por preconceito ou seja lá o que for isso?"

Creio que esse "não estão entendendo" possa se aplicar a mais de um lado.

Você está fazendo uma afirmação sobre o comportamento dos outros como se fosse uma certeza. Só no meu caso específico, já é a segunda vez que você faz essa suposição e está enganado, por exemplo.

Já parou pra pensar que talvez o motivo seja outro? Por exemplo, dou upvotes em várias perguntas autorespondidas, baseadas em relevância e de fato nas boas respostas (inclusive algumas suas). Outras não, e o meu critério é relevância e forma.

Detalhe: a limitação de que você mencionou na outra resposta sobre mostrar KBs é mero erro de digitação, talvez se você tivesse aberto à resposta do colega tivesse notado o erro e corrigido até. Quanto a ser melhor ou não, os votos em geral a médio prazo vão dizer.

A comunidade está tentando te dar um feedback, talvez em vez de mudar toda a comunidade apenas, todos possamos nos ajustar em vez de considerar que tudo é "birra".

Obviamente que essa é minha opinião individual, espero que sirva como termômetro para todos.

Comment: +115 / -0: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4975942/340760 Vai continuar dizendo que não é "birra"?

Comment: PS: Como eu disse antes, naturalmente os votos a médio prazo vão dizer o que é bom ou não. 4 ou 5 não querem dizer nada. Um detalhe, ja tive questão que levou dias até chegar na que havia sido mais votada.