# Responder sua própria pergunta

Tags: debate, responder-a-si-mesmo

## Responder sua própria pergunta

Um dos primeiros posts no Meta já dizia:

> - **Quando você tiver um problema, pergunte.** Mesmo que você acabe descobrindo a resposta, vai ajudar alguém com o mesmo problema no futuro. Se possível, espere um dia para ver se alguém aparece com uma solução tão boa quanto a sua, se não acontecer, responda você mesmo.
> - **Faça perguntas sobre coisas que te deram dor de cabeça no passado.** Lembre-se das vezes em que você simplesmente não conseguiu encontrar uma boa resposta online para o seu problema, ou quando a resposta era incompleta e precisava de mais detalhes, e escreva sobre elas aqui.

Pelo visto eles não eram muito claros em estabelecer uma regra básica do Stack Overflow (em qualquer língua):

### Você pode responder suas próprias perguntas

Então...

- Se você tem um problema que já sabe a resposta
- Se você gostaria de tornar a sua resposta pública, para que qualquer pessoa possa ler no futuro (inclusive você)
- Você pode fazer sua pergunta e respondê-la aqui.

**Não é apenas permitido, é algo que nós apoiamos totalmente.**

Depois de encarar um problema difícil, batendo bastante a cabeça pra conseguir arrumar uma solução, nada melhor que postar sobre ele aqui, descrevendo o que aconteceu e como você conseguiu resolver. Talvez outras pessoas até postem mais soluções ainda melhores que a sua. Todo mundo sai ganhando.

## Mas.. mas... isso não é ganhar ponto de graça?

Não há pré-requisito de sofrimento legítimo, ou de veracidade do problema, para que uma pergunta seja feita aqui no site. Responder sua própria pergunta causa exatamente 0 problemas.

Se alguém receber um monte de pontos por uma pergunta que ela mesma respondeu, é porque o post ajudou alguém e esse é o objetivo aqui. Responder sua própria pergunta não é garantia de que você vai receber milhões de pontos de internet e poder comprar a sua casa própria. Os pontos são uma avaliação da **qualidade** e **utilidade** de uma post. Se o autor de uma pergunta e sua resposta receber vários votos, parabéns por ter criado um conteúdo que ajudou a várias pessoas.

## Todas as perguntas são iguais aos olhos da comunidade

No fim das contas, avalie uma pergunta sempre da mesma forma. Se a pergunta for de baixa qualidade, vote, alerte, comente. Ela ter sido respondida pelo próprio autor não é sinal de que ela deve passar por um crivo mais, ou menos, exigente.

Tenha sempre em mente que o propósito principal do Stack Overflow é ajudar a comunidade de desenvolvedores de língua portuguesa, e compartilhar seu conhecimento é a melhor forma de fazer isso.

Comment: Concordo com tudo o que está escrito, tanto que já falei sobre isso antes. Sei que não é o objetivo deste post, mas votos negativos ou positivos dados por outros critérios também são válidos, apesar de eu não incentivar. Votar positivamente em uma resposta melhor e negativamente em uma resposta certa, porém, pior, também é uma forma de diferenciar a qualidade. Gabe, aproveitando que você está ativo no meta neste momento, tem várias questões abertas que precisariam da sua participação para dar feedback para a comunidade.

Comment: @Gabe O fato de estarmos no início do site então é irrelevante, posso começar a perguntar e responder da mesma forma que o faria em um site já graduado? Tem muita coisa que me deu dor-de-cabeça no passado e que eu gostaria de "documentar" aqui, só estava me segurando porque achei que isso atrapalharia a comunidade de crescer organicamente. Devo interpretar esse post como um "sinal verde" pra seguir em frente?

Comment: @mgibsonbr Com certeza. Esse tipo de "documentação" é ainda mais importante agora. Sinta-se à vontade.

Comment: Zero problemas não é o que temos visto aqui. Pelo contrário, tem muita gente incomodada com as perguntas que têm brotado artificialmente no site, especialmente quando são do mesmo usuário, e quando não são exatamente "próprias", e sim traduções de perguntas frequentes do site original. Eu sou sim a favor de responder às próprias perguntas (inclusive, minha pergunta e resposta com mais votos no SO são um caso desses), e no início achava que seria bom colocar esse tipo de pergunta aqui desde cedo, mas mudei de idéia.

Comment: Aproveitando, outro post inicial aqui do meta dizia que o SOpt seria o site que *nós* queremos construir, mas o tom deste seu post me parece mais a imposição de uma regra do que uma tentativa de diálogo com a comunidade.

Comment: @bfavaretto A única "imposição" é a de que não vai havernenhuma imposição de verdade. Houve uma quantidade razoável de flags que eram nada além de "o autor respondeu sua própria pergunta pra ganhar pontos", posts no meta sobre o mesmo assunto. Eu queria esclarecer pra todo mundo que não existe problema **nenhum** em fazer isso. Problemas em relação à qualidade e/ou quantidade desses posts (ou de traduções do SO), devem ser lidados de outra forma

Comment: Gabe, fico feliz em saber que não haverá imposição alguma. É que estranhei este post em forma de "anúncio", sendo que já havia outras duas perguntas onde isto poderia ser postado como resposta. E quanto aos flags, concordo com você, não é a maneira de se lidar com isso.

Comment: Eu acho que seria importante que a pergunta explicitasse que ou (1) o OP já sabe a resposta ou (2) a própria resposta dentro da pergunta. Também é importante que o OP explicite a intenção de sua pergunta. Uma coisa é você dizer que não sabe, outra é dizer que sabe mas quer melhorá-la. Para quem está respondendo, a dinâmica é diferente (na minha opinião). Obrigado pelo trabalho de moderação.

Answer (score 12):

Já tinha comentado que concordo com tudo o que está escrito neste post. Então quais são os problemas dele?

Primeiro, o que não está escrito nele. Está analisando um ponto que me parece que, se não todo mundo, pelo menos a maioria concorda. Unanimidade é muito difícil de obter e não será este post que conseguirá isso. O que realmente precisaria se discutir é a qualidade do que está sendo postado e porque as pessoas votam.

E ainda dá a impressão que alguém está querendo proibir esse tipo de atitude. O que as pessoas estão preocupadas é com a imagem que a comunidade vai passar. Já teve quem era a contra a criação do site e veio me dizer "*está vendo, mal começou e já está cheio de perguntas bobas*", esse é o real problema.

Eu aprendi com o Robert Cartaino que o início do site é muito importante para dar o tom do site. Se o tom que o SE quer dar é de que aqui será um site de traduções do SO, era melhor criar o site para ser isso. Me lembro que o Robert deu opinião sobre uma questão inicial minha que eu considerava como básica em todo site e na época achava que ela era útil e que não fazia diferença se estava em beta ou não, mas que muitos consideram muito ruim para dar o tom. Eu me convenci que ele estava certo. Agora não é mais importante dar o tom correto?

O Robert bate muito na tecla de que se o site não atrair os especialistas, ele não vai pra frente. Alguns foram fechados por causa disso. E já teve caso da equipe ter que pedir desculpas por ter criado problemas para a comunidade depois de não ouvir o que todos estavam dizendo. Se passarmos a imagem errada, não atrair os especialistas e o site virar um repositório de traduções, o que a equipe vai fazer? Assumir a responsabilidade será tarde demais.

As pessoas fazem o que elas veem sendo feitas em um ambiente.

Segundo, parece uma imposição. E parece por alguns motivos. Para saber se essa aparência está equivocada, precisamos saber algumas coisas:

- O que disparou a necessidade deste post? Ele parece ter saído do nada, já que não está vinculado de nenhuma forma a qualquer outra coisa. Ele parece asséptico.
- A frase "*Pelo visto eles não eram muito claros em estabelecer uma regra básica do Stack Overflow*" deve ter sido colocada porque há indicativos que não há essa compreensão. Onde estão esses indicativos?
- No post [Como construir o site que você quer ser quando crescer](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2/como-construir-o-site-que-voce-quer-ser-quando-crescer) o "você" significa SE?
- Porque esse post é tão importe e outras necessidades da comunidade não são? Difere do que se costuma ver nas comunidades SE. O que levanta outro ponto, mas como é off-topic, vou abrir outro post para isso, [aqui](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/424/como-funciona-a-relacao-da-comunidade-do-sopt-com-a-se-inc).
- Não seria melhor, perguntar abrindo o debate ao invés apenas de afirmar e não se envolver com o que realmente é problema?
- Porque o assunto não foi tratado onde a comunidade já está discutindo o assunto? [Respondi minha própria pergunta, fiz algo errado?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/37/respondi-minha-propria-pergunta-fiz-algo-errado)

Note que eu não tenho nenhum problema em trazer traduções e até posso fazer isso em algum momento. Eu quero trazer o melhor conteúdo do SO para cá. Eu quero produzir um conteúdo inédito em português, que use o conteúdo em inglês no SO original como referência. Mas queremos trazer artificialmente, principalmente no começo, o que está escrito na introdução de qualquer livro introdutório? E isso é bem diferente de dizer que novatos não possam perguntar coisas básicas, que não possa ter conteúdo básico de forma alguma em algum momento.

Eu não ligo muito pelo [ganho de reputação](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19522/140010) honesto da forma que for. Mas muitas pessoas se preocupam. A minha preocupação é se essas pessoas estão se irritando com isso e se podemos abrir mão delas. A posição oficial é que essas pessoas devem ser ignoradas?

E tudo isso parece ir um pouco contra o que foi dito [nessa resposta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/11/traducao-de-perguntas-e-faqs/19#19). Pode ser uma impressão errada, mas não teria essa impressão se o post aqui estivesse olhando os dois lados da moeda como foi feito na resposta indicada.

Não adianta aplicar uma regra sem olhar o que está acontecendo. O conteúdo do site é sobre ciência exata mas a comunidade não é.

Comment: conforme o Gabe falou nos comentários, os indicativos foram uma série de flags. Rapaz, concordo com você sobre a questão de atrair os especialistas. Mas sugiro que releia o seu post e repare como às vezes o texto insinua ignorância e má-fé dos outros, mesmo não sendo mal-educado. Esse comportamento passivo-agressivo é o tipo de coisa que afasta gente legal.

Comment: Eu, pelo menos, já li muita coisa aqui no meta que mais desencoraja participar do que encoraja. =/

Comment: Acho que essa resposta está precisando ser atualizada. Isso foi escrito sobre a perspectiva deste site ser um beta privado.

Comment: @VictorStafusa é, preciso mexer, se quiser mudar algo fica a vontade...