# Onde estão os membros programadores de ActionScript?

Tags: debate, perguntas-sem-resposta

Há muito tempo venho utilizando o **SOen** para minhas pesquisas em relação a linguagem **ActionScript** da Adobe e hoje tenho um pouco de experiência e conhecimento que sinto vontade de compartilhar com a nova comunidade em português.

Hoje no **SOpt** não há muitos membros realizando perguntas sobre a linguagem e muitas das minhas questões não são respondidas ou eu mesmo tenho que respondê-las (Sempre pesquisando em sites no Google em inglês).

O que podemos fazer para melhorar o número de membros sobre essa linguagem?

Sinto-me frustado ao saber que não há ninguém* para eu trocar experiências.

Comment: Provavelmente, usuários AS não estão ativos aqui no SOpt ainda. Acredito que você continuar perguntando e respondendo vai criar um repositório de perguntas e por fim atrair usuários. Foi assim que fui atraído ao SO. Finalmente, não sei se o meta é o lugar para discutir assuntos como esse. :S

Comment: A pergunta foi colocada em suspenso, sem ao menos eu saber o motivo. Onde, então, devemos discutir isso? Já era de se esperar que o começo do SOpt seria apenas uma luta pra ganhar reputação. Acredito que ainda existam muitos usuários daqui fazendo isso e talvez essa seja uma das causas dos usuários AS3 não estarem aqui.

Comment: Bom, eu não posso falar pelos outros e nem tenho atualmente reputação suficiente para colocar nada em suspenso. Mas abaixo da nota informando que foi colocada em suspenso está o motivo, explicando que a pergunta está descontextualizada. Acho que o problema maior é essa parte da sua pergunta: "Ainda vale a pena investir no AS3? Eu deveria trocar ou focar em outra linguagem de programação? Que posição eu devo tomar?". Responder isso com certeza não está relacionado com o SOpt.

Comment: Bom, eu editei, vamos ver o que acontece agora.

Comment: Eu sou um programador de AS3 (vi outros aqui), o problema ao meu ver é que as outras linguagens estão tão em alta que o AS3 tem estado com o mercado em baixa, mesmo para projetos desktop feitos em AdobeAir. Eu pessoalmente me interesso pelos projetos web, mas o adobe-flash carece de algumas funcionalides que as APIs JavaScript (estou falando de código nativo) já superam o Flash, os swfs acabaram que ficando como "alternativas" ou só usado para players de video/audio. Um exemplo funcionalidade simples e legal para o AdobeAir que não tem no Flash é arrastar arquivos para o `stage`.

Answer (score 5):

A comunidade é nova e ainda não está difundida no Brasil. A falta de questões sobre a linguagem **ActionScript** não significa que a linguagem seja ruim e você deva escolher outra. Com o tempo poderá aparecer pessoas com dúvidas a respeito e você poderá colaborar.

Comment: Mas sem dúvida a linguagem está em declínio, em termos de quantidade de usuários.

Comment: @bfavaretto eu mesmo já trabalhei com ActionScript, hoje em dia não vejo vantagem, visto que tablets e smartphones não rodam Flash, mas para quem gosta de desenvolver jogos ou outras aplicações específicas, ainda tem mercado.

Comment: Gosto do AS pelo fato de ser Multiplataforma, porém, rodar em cima de uma VM é o que ainda inviabiliza o uso da linguagem. Você citou Tablets e Smartphones que não rodam Flash, mas com a VM do Adobe AIR é possível realizar aplicações e até mesmo jogos para os mesmos. Na web, muitos trabalhos em 3D são feitos com Flash e, levando em considerações as empresas de DS, o Flash é uma ferramenta muito útil. Não entendo este "preconceito" em relação ao Flash, o que eu vejo é uma mudança de foco.

Comment: @biio não é preconceito, a realidade é que o flash caiu em desuso, e cada vez menos haverá gente a usar flash. O lado bom é que como no C a nível avançado, pouca gente sabe e são muito bem pagos.

Comment: Isso é um ponto forte pro bolso, mas um ponto fraco para a troca de conhecimento, sinto que ainda tenho muito a Aprender com AS3, principalmente em relação ao Adobe AIR e Native Extensions.

Answer (score 5):

Você pode criar perguntas e responder você mesmo, assim você aumentará o conteúdo do assunto no site fazendo que ele ganhe mais visibilidade nos resultados de buscadores como o Google, Bing, Baidu e etc.

Leia mais em: [Responder sua própria pergunta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/422/3117)