# Ganhei a medalha Necromante sem ganhar a medalha Ressurgimento

Tags: suporte, medalhas

Olhando a descrição das medalhas eu diria que isso é algo impossível:

> **Ressurgimento**
>   Respondeu depois de mais de 30 dias com uma pontuação de 2 ou superior
>
> **Necromante**
>   Respondeu uma pergunta depois de mais de 60 dias com uma pontuação de 5 ou superior

Entretanto aconteceu comigo hoje ao responder a pergunta [Onde estão os membros programadores de ActionScript?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1209/3117).

#### Ressurgimento [**(link aqui)**](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/64/revival?userid=3117):

[image: ressurgimento]

#### Necromante [**(link aqui)**](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/17/necromancer?userid=3117):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Fazendo uma busca pela comunidade vi mais algumas pessoas em situação similar. Vejam por exemplo esse usuário [Leandro Amorim](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/3032/leandro-amorim):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Fora ele tem mais casos por aí.

Isso seria um bug? Ou existe alguma outra explicação para tal fato?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

É totalmente contraintuitivo, mas [segundo o FAQ da Comunidade no MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions) a medalha de bronze tem um requisito a mais:

> No other answers posted earlier than your answer have a score of two. "Earlier" refers to the time the answer was originally posted (first revision).

Ou seja, você só ganha a medalha se nenhuma resposta anterior à sua tiver pontuação de 2 ou mais.

Comment: Eu já tinha lido a descrição da medalha no SOEN e achava que aquela descrição estava errada também: "Answered more than 30 days later as first answer scoring 2 or more", mas agora lendo de novo e sabendo o real significado vejo que ela está correta sim, pois vc deve ter a resposta que seja a primeira a fazer 2 ou mais, e o q eu entendia antes era que a sua tinha que ser a primeira, e ela deveria ter 2 ou mais. Sendo assim, não seria o caso de mudar a tag da pergunta para bug de tradução? Ou talvez criar uma nova? Pois nossa tradução está errada, e me levou ao equívoco dessa pergunta aqui.

Comment: Criei: [Má tradução: Medalha Ressurgimento](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1770/3117)