# Será que é realmente importante fazer perguntas no meta?

Tags: debate

Eu estava pensando aqui se fazer perguntas no meta é realmente importante.

Será que qualquer conclusão chegada nos debates por aqui vai fazer alguma diferença?

Será que invés de a gente está estudando e aprendendo, estamos perdendo tempo com debates que não irão fazer alguma diferença em nada no site ?

Comment: Há mais de 2000 pergunta no meta neste momento, você precisa ser mais especifico que isso.

Comment: eu me refiro a fazer perguntas no meta

Comment: E qual o problema disso? Você entendeu a finalidade do meta? Sugiro ler com calma este link e meditar se realmente não é importante: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta

Comment: endetdi sim ! <br/>
fazer perguntas sobre como funciona o site <br/>
fazer perguntas da comunidade <br/>
publicar bugs<br/>
sugerir melhorias<br/>
propor novos recursos<br/>
sera que isso e realmente importante ?sera que vai fazer alguma diferença ? sera que de tantas sujestoes, ta realmente se transformando em algum beneficio para i site?

Comment: Para julgar o meta como algo não relevante, com certeza não!

Comment: aki e assim ...
agente faz uma pergunta voçes mudam a pergunta toda!
agente faz uma pergunta e nao pode fazer outra !
aki ninguem pode fazer nada

Comment: Cara você está reclamando de uma coisa que nem sequer entende o funcionamento. E tags HTML não funcionam em comentarios. E seria interessante apresentar links dos casos em que diz que "nós mudamos a pergunta toda". O site é colaborativo, faz parte da filosofia "editar e melhorar".

Comment: hum rum sei ,e eu nao to reclamando  de nada .
so tou dando minha humilde opinião e resolvir fazer uma pergunta no meta talvez voçe nao gostou mais eu queria ver a opiniao dos outros se fosse posivel

Comment: Eu já tirei algumas dúvidas sobre a plataforma pelo Meta e me ajudaram muito. O que não faz sentido e é perda de tempo é debater se o Meta funciona ou não. (mesmo assim me permiti perder esse tempo para abrir seus olhos). Se não está gostando tem outras plataforma e até grupos no Facebook, só com coisa de alto nível #sqn []´s

Comment: Uma dúvida: Se o meta é perda de tempo, por quê você usou ele para fazer uma pergunta? É bastante contraditório(e paradoxal rs).

Comment: acho que o unico lugar mais adequado pra fazer essa pergunta e aqui mesmo

Comment: Entendo, mas sua pergunta demonstra que você não entendeu a real utilidade deste site. O meta é para que usuários novos e antigos reportem problemas, tirem dúvidas sobre funcionalidades, abram discussões relevantes para melhorias e até sobre comportamentos no site principal. O meta é como se fosse uma espécie de "SAC" do stackoverflow, só que ao invés de funcionários da empresa proprietária do site, quem responde quase sempre são outros membros.

Comment: @Danilorodrigues porque removeu? achei a pergunta interessante.

Comment: Restaurei a pergunta porque também achei interessante, @Maniero. Danilo, se quiser muito manter a pergunta excluída, podemos bater um papo no chat ok?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### AAAAAAAAH, O META!

Cá estou eu, entre os, digamos, menos experientes do site. Não me lembro de postar uma resposta aqui, mas vou em frente, ou melhor, atrás. Vou rebobinar algumas coisinhas das minhas primeiras dúvidas sobre programação. Lembro-me que não sabia por onde começar, se via a confusa documentação das linguagens, se batia um papo com meus amigos programadores (que nunca são muitos, rsrs), e enfim, descobri o StackOverflow.

Não vou te julgar, mal conheço você e outros tantos **milhares** de novos usuários (ou menos experientes) que o SO tem. Mas como tudo na vida é um aprendizado, consegui me "adequar" ao comportamento do site.

O StackOverflow é um paraíso livre para programadores entusiastas que querem aprender codificar. O problema é que nem sempre querer é poder. Digamos que estamos em uma sala de aula querendo muito aprender, mas não temos lápis, borracha, folha e nem ao menos nos importamos com que o professor escreve na lousa. Para isso você tem que se "adequar".

Como fazemos para criar um padrão de adequação? Militamos um único ser a decidir o que é melhor para todos? Entregamos nas mãos dos criadores do site para fazer isso por nós? Não, simplesmente criamos um ambiente de discussão que trata de assuntos sobre "como podemos fazer para aprender melhor nessa sala de aula?".

Enfim, é para isso que serve o Meta, no meu mais singelo e inocente ponto de vista. Quando vemos algo de errado é pra cá que vamos! Quando temos uma sugestão [como você mesmo postou um dia](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6828/que-tal-um-chat-aberto-com-os-assuntos-mais-badalados), chegamos aqui! Quando não concordamos com alguma coisa, [como nesse exemplo](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6857/discord%C3%A2ncia-quanto-ao-fechamento-da-quest%C3%A3o-n%C3%A3o-%C3%A9-duplicata), nós debatemos aqui! E sim, nem sempre conseguimos reverter algo que queremos muito, e isso acontece muitas e muitas vezes, [eu que o diga, como na minha primeira postagem no meta, sem muito entender o que era, kkkkk](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1209/onde-est%C3%A3o-os-membros-programadores-de-actionscript).

A versão principal existe há quase 10 anos. Esse site existe há quase 5. Você tem 13 dias de cadastro. Talvez você, assim como eu, tenha que entender um pouco sobre como funcionam as coisas por aqui. Garanto a você que não irá se arrepender.

É isso. Paaaaaaaz.

Comment: muito obrigado !

Answer (score 6):

> Será que invés de a gente estar estudando e aprendendo, estamos perdendo tempo com debates que não irão fazer alguma diferença em nada no site?

Talvez, mas não dá pra saber, né? Eu acho que pelo menos é melhor tentarmos discutir os problemas do site do que fazer de conta que eles não existem. E pra isso o lugar é o meta.

Concordo que muitos debates não são efetivos, e acho que isso acontece por vários motivos. Um deles é que apenas alguns poucos usuários realmente participam do meta.

Answer (score 4):

> estamos perdendo tempo com debates que não irão fazer alguma diferença em nada no site?

Descobrir a resposta para isso é simples, apesar de ser trabalhoso. Verifique cada pergunta no Meta e veja o impacto que teve no site. Daí aplique a seguinte fórmula:

```
quantidade de perguntas que tiveram impacto no site / quantidade total de perguntas
```

O resultado vai ser um número entre zero e um (limites inclusivos). Esse número é o *"fator de eficiência"* do Meta.

Alguns tipos de pergunta farão a equação tender ao valor máximo:

- Perguntas sobre bugs;
- Perguntas sobre orientação;
- Perguntas sobre ajustes de tradução;
- Perguntas sobre o que faz parte do escopo;
- Perguntas sobre perguntas específicas;
- Anúncios.

Perguntas sobre o sexo dos anjos, ou que não deveriam estar no Meta, farão o fator tender a zero. Sobre essas, a impressão que tenho é que elas são minoria.

Comment: Eu acho que algumas perguntas sobre tags _as vezes_ roda e roda e roda sem tantas definições. Mas as vezes esse rodar e rodar e rodar é um passo necessário no amadurecimento das ideias

Answer (score 3):

> Eu estava pensando aqui se fazer perguntas no meta é realmente importante.

Sim é importante, desde que entenda o que é o Meta e para que server

> Será que qualquer conclusão chegada nos debates por aqui vai fazer alguma diferença?

Claro que sim, haverá situações aonde são desnecessárias, mas se entende o que é o Meta e tem experiencia entendendo o que é o Stack Overflow e que tem uma empresa por trás dele e que nem tudo o que queremos é de interesse da empresa dará para você se focar em coisas mais produtivas

> Será que invés de a gente está estudando e aprendendo, estamos perdendo tempo com debates que não irão fazer alguma diferença em nada no site ?

O Meta não tem nada haver com resolver seus problemas pessoais das suas perguntas, muito menos suporte, o foco do Meta é ajudar sobre:

- BUGs no site principal
- Comportamento (como agir) no site principal
- Analisar perguntas ou respostas com problemas (não erros), tipo foi fechada indevidamente

O Meta serve se você entende o foco dele, se não entende ainda é claro que ele vai parecer inútil, aqui não tem nada haver com estudar e/ou aprender algo, como eu disse anteriormente **não somos uma comunidade de professores de programação** que veem aqui para dar aula ou **alunos que viemos para ter aulas aqui**, somos uma comunidade de profissionais e entusiastas, cada um com seus próprios interesses, e para atuar na comunidade é preciso entender isto:

- a ferramenta
- as regras

---

### Sobre o veto

Todas suas perguntas no Meta sempre me parecem dificuldade sobre o uso do site principal, eu realmente acho que você ainda esta **vetado** para estar fazendo estas perguntas aqui, não é assim que você vai resolver o problema, fazendo suposições sem entender o que aconteceu, como eu disse na outra resposta, se esta com um problema que esta bloqueado de fazer novas perguntas no site principal (isso é o veto) então siga as instruções:

- https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/6475/3635

Acesse este link e veja o que você pode restaurar e tentar melhorar:

- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A105535+is%3Aquestion%20deleted%3A1

Só assim você vai conseguir resolver os seus problemas de uso do site e não afirmando que o Meta é o problema, o Meta é, além de um lugar para resolver os tipos de problemas já citados, um lugar com perguntas e respostas já prontas que vocÊ pode pesquisar, tem muitas perguntas (não as suas) que são até duplicatas de assuntos já muito debatidos e que já tem respostas.

Comment: Sobre o que é ser _meta_, origem da palavra e significado, essa resposta no site principal define: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/281404/64969