# Discordância quanto ao fechamento da questão, não é duplicata

Tags: debate, pergunta-específica

Eu discordo quanto ao entendimento da comunidade de que esta pergunta é duplicada: [Os operadores ==, ===, != e !== podem ser considerador de "lógica difusa"?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/280978/64969)

Pergunta que responderia essa questão: [Qual a diferença entre os operadores == e === em JavaScript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/7/64969)

A pergunta fechada pergunta não sobre o que faz cada operador, mas sim se eles poderiam ser considerados como operadores de lógica *fuzzy*. Já as respostas na outra perguntam se preocupam apenas em definir de maneira inequívoca sobre o que cada operador faz e nuances. Mas não falam sobre considerar *fuzzy* ou não. Então, não vejo o porquê delas serem consideradas equivalentes.

Aproveitando, excerto da resposta fechada:

> OBS: A dúvida **não é** sobre a diferença entre eles, e sim, se levando em conta a lógica matemática apenas se podemos considerar como operadores de **logica difusa**, ou seja, de igualdade baseada em proporção.

Então, devido a isso, votei pela reabertura da questão.

PS: para não deixar o entendimento faltoso, eu mesmo coloquei [um comentário com um link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/280978/os-operadores-e-podem-ser-considerador-de-l%c3%b3gica-difusa?noredirect=1#comment574910_280978) para que o autor saiba do assunto.

### Atualização

A pergunta já foi reaberta.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sim a pergunta deve ser reaberta.

Inicialmente eu votei para fechar como duplicata, tanto que o primeiro voto foi meu mesmo, mas eu o removi quando finalmente entendi a pergunta.

O maior problema que levou ao fechamento foi uma falta de uma introdução sobre **lógica difusa**, claro que o fechamento foi errado, mas a pratica em escrever ou dar uma boa intro para o problema é o que faz alguma diferença, não é que o autor deveria explicar o que é lógica difusa, mas o texto original parece dar mais foco aos operadores e acaba que só no final que lemos sobre lógica difusa:

> A dúvida é simples e apenas por curiosidade, num ponto de vista matemático, pode-se considerar os operadores de comparação:
>
> ==
>
> ===
>
> !=
>
> !==
>
> Como operadores de comparação de logica difusa ?

O autor falava, num ponto de *vista matematico*, isto realmente soou estranho, acabei me focando no que eram os operadores e que eles não tinham relação em comparação matematica diretamente.

Olhando de um ponto de vista diferente daria para dizer que por eles servirem para comparar valores e tipos não são necessariamente múltiplos valores, mas sim valor ou tipo apenas, então acabou que provavelmente os votos que vieram após a edição que o autor fez e que eu tentei clarear para tentar melhorar a pergunta podem ter sido neste mesmo entendimento:

- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/280978/revisions

Mas é claro que ainda sim a pergunta é necessária e especifica e a outra pergunta não cobre ela de ponto algum e por este motivo também votei para reabrir.