# Stackoverflow é um local que privilegia sanguessugas?

Tags: debate

Sei que posso tomar um monte de negativo na minha pergunta e até ser banido, mas eu preciso perguntar isso.
90% das minhas dúvidas eu consigo resolver pesquisando no Google, que fatalmente me joga pra alguns dos sites da Stack e a solução tá lá, linda! (E nos outros 10% eu pesquiso aqui de forma diferente e também consigo a solução!)
O problema está na hora de tentar ajudar alguém.
Para um novato, o processo de tentar auxiliar é extremamente burocrático e engessado.
Estou em um [caso](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/308801/d%C3%BAvida-sobre-classes) que quero ajudar a pessoa em uma resposta extremamente simples, mas ela foi trancada, pois quem leu simplesmente não entendeu o problema e agora é praticamente impossível tentar reabrir. Já tentei editar, sinalizar e até entrar em contato com quem trancou, mas sou simplesmente ignorado.
Isso me leva a crer que é muito mais fácil ser ajudado do que tentar ajudar....
Ai vem minha pergunta: Aqui é mais fácil ser um sanguessuga?

Pra mim, é muito cômodo ficar de boa e continuar só sugando, pois se eu for banido, o Google vai continuar trazendo as respostas, mas sinceramente, é muito desmotivante tentar ajudar por aqui.

OBS: Não estou criticando a pessoa quem moderou a pergunta, muito menos questionando seus titulos ou méritos, pois acredito que ela fez por merecer, estou exemplificando o caso para demonstrar o quanto é difícil ajudar.

Comment: `Para um novato, o processo de tentar auxiliar é extremamente burocrático e engessado` -  defina o porquê dessa afirmação, porque isso pra mim beira ao desconhecimento do funcionamento do site. Qualquer usuário(inclusive aqueles q nem tem conta) podem responder no site, nao tem burocracia alguma, exceto pelo fato de nao poder comentar, mas se uma pergunta necessita de mais esclarecimentos, é porque ela não foi feita clara o suficiente para ter uma resposta. Provavelmente foi o caso desta do exemplo.

Comment: Eu ainda estou tentando entender a relação entre sua crítica ao fato da pergunta estar fechada quanto a palavra sangessuga. Pois pela minha experiencia aqui, sanguessuga ;e justamente quem faz o contrario, sai perguntando de qualquer jeito, sem ser claro e sem apresentar codigo relevante, e aguarda uma solucao do céu. Ficou meio confuso isso. Quem tem alta reputação, ao menos a grande maioria, é porque dedicou parte de seu tempo em compartilhar conhecimento. Reputação é apenas um número, nao diz nada demais.

Comment: E, não, não é caso de ban abrir o coração e questionar o comportamento da comunidade. É assim que se aprende, é assim que a comunidade passa a ter auto-consciência de seus atos para tentar se corrigir (ou se fortalecer, caso o questionamento de seu comportamento não se mostre fundamentado o suficiente para o contexto)

Comment: Ajudar não é simplesmente ter boa vontade, não é gastar seu tempo com boa intenção, não é gastar 4 horas e textos longos, e não é proporcional ao esforço de quem "ajudou". Ajudar é a ação de quem tem condição técnica e de comunicação para postar o que as outras pessoas precisam de fato, e seguindo um contexto estabelecido, no nosso caso. Postar algo baseado na suposição de ser o único a entender geralmente não é ajudar, é ser sanguessuga. Quer ajudar? Entenda melhor o site, aí você pode ajudar o autor a melhorar a pergunta de forma que ela possa ser reaberta e todos se beneficiem.

Answer (score 23):

> Stackoverflow é um local que privilegia sanguessugas?

De forma geral sim.

As respostas do Jefferson Quesado e do hkotsubo são muito boas falando nisso.

Meu gosto é que privilegiasse bem menos. E privilegiasse bem mais que responde. E isso meio que está cada vez mais ao contrário.

Talvez a SE esteja certa em um aspecto. A maioria das pessoas gostam do formato mais solto. Já vi usuários bons de conteúdo dizendo que gosta, embora muitos dizendo o oposto também.

É fato que hoje o SOen e o SOpt tem ilhas de bons conteúdos e o resto é medíocre, ruim e ainda sobra muita coisa que é puro lixo (desculpe pelo palavreado científico). Todos aqui sabem disto e não vale a pena usar eufemismos ou fazer de conta que não é isso. Só acha diferente quem não vive o dia a dia, é fácil criticar de fora sem ter o fardo de administrar tudo isto.

Eu tenho até mudado de opinião sobre a qualidade de conteúdo e forma de atender a demanda. percebi que as pessoas gostam mesmo é de fórum onde tem um monte de coisa repetida, feita de qualquer jeito, em que a resposta de qualidade muitas vezes não é valorizada, onde precisa vários passos para fazer a pergunta atingir o ponto onde dá para dar a solução completa e correta, e no final se ficar tudo desorganizado, tudo bem. Sério, estou dizendo que o melhor seria ter ferramentas melhores para gerir um fórum. Mas não acontecerá.

Inclusive as pessoas adoram debater assuntos e uma ferramenta boa pra moderar isto seria muito melhor que proibir. Até o fundador do SO já falou disso no Twitter recentemente. E gostam de *poll/survey/list*. Tudo precisa da ferramenta certa.

Por outro lado o conteúdo de qualidade deveria ter mais destaque, mais debatido, deveria ser mais canônico, algo como um *overhaaul* de wiki.

Tem muito o que falar sobre isso, muito o que muda na ferramenta para se adequar. O SO ficou meio que um pato.

[image: Pato anda, nada e voa e faz tudo ruim]

Então eu tenho um lado que acha que deveria dificultar, ser mais elitista pra privilegiar a qualidade. Não sei se daria certo, mas adoraria.

Por outro lado sei que para agradar mais é liberar mais, privilegiar os sugadores (*suckers*?), atenderia melhor à população de devs. E a qualidade iria pro vinagre de vez, mas tudo tem dois lados. Por esta visão, e a ferramenta ajudando, deveria deixar "tudo", deveria todos poderem ajudar a verdade, e assumirem as consequências, inclusive nenhuma e aceitar que a maioria do conteúdo será ajuda frívola mesmo, o que já ocorre em grande parte, só não vê quem não quer.

Eu queria ferramentas muito melhores para quem produz conteúdo, muito mesmo. Dá para fazer, mas provavelmente não importa mais. E as melhorias que se faz hoje são bem pontuais e demora bastante. Pode estar certo sob um ponto de vista. Pela [teoria de Schumpeter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creative_destruction) abre a porta para surgir outra *startup* que fça isso melhor e consiga atrair as pessoas certas para tudo mudar. O SO nasceu para ser o site que sem querer propunha troca de sexo e o YR!.

Enfim, o assunto não é o foco da pergunta, mas vez ou outra lanço ideias pra ver se alguém resolve discutir isso seriamente.

> Sei que posso tomar um monte de negativo na minha pergunta

Aconteceu porque a pergunta fo feita de qualquer jeito, como sanguessugas costumam fazer, segundo uma definição possível, e porque parte de pressupostos errados, não resolve problema algum e faz alguns ataques. Soa de um jeito um pouco diferente para quem está aqui todos os dias há anos ajudando as milhares de pessoas sem ganhar nada com isso. Tudo tem o outro lado. Pensou nisso?

> e até ser banido

Só diz isso porque não conhece as regras e a cultura do site, o que já indica porque a reclamação não é lá tão pertinente assim, pelo menos na forma realizada.

> Para um novato, o
>   processo de tentar auxiliar é extremamente burocrático e engessado.

Para um experiente é muito mais, até porque estes costumam fazer dezenas ou centenas de vezes todos os dias. Quem não faz isto seria um sanguessuga?

> Estou em um caso que quero ajudar a pessoa em uma resposta
>   extremamente simples

Que ótimo, ajudas são apreciadas!

> mas ela foi trancada, pois quem leu simplesmente
>   não entendeu o problema

Várias pessoas leram, neste momento mais de 70. Parece que ninguém entendeu.

> e agora é praticamente impossível tentar reabrir

Por que acha isto? Pode argumentar porque ela não deveria ser fechada? Vou ressaltar que preciso de argumentos, não que acha que deveria estar aberta, isso já notamos. E note que o fechamento foi realizado antes da versão atual.

> Já tentei editar

[Não há edição sua](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/308801/revisions), uma [tentativa foi recusada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/173813) por um moderador eleito (recebeu a confiança da comunidade qua participa aqui com afinco) que é muito cuidadoso, e um usuário de altíssima reputação aqui e que dá o sangue pelo site, e que viram que a edição desfigurava a pergunta e não a melhorava nada, e eu concordo com ele, acredito que todos os usuários experientes vão concordam também. Se discordasse, eu faria o que é possível para reverter uma decisão equivocada. Teve [outra edição recusada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/173716) por outros usuários e que me parece ter sido uma tentativa mais absurda ainda.

> sinalizar

Eu recusei uma sinalização porque para reabrir tem um processo próprio, inclusive a edição feita, e ela entrou na fila, vários usuários viram e decidiram que não deveriam reabrir, a decisão é tomada por um colegiado, inclusive que participou é usuário de alta reputação, extramente dedicado e respeitado pela comunidade, outro com conhecimento forte sobre o assunto específico, além de outro que tem feito um bom trabalho e está evoluindo (e ele foi o primeiro, não foi no embalo dos outros)

> e até entrar em contato com quem trancou,

É, e não me agradou nem um pouco, minhas redes sociais é para contatos pessoas e profissionais, não para resolver questão do site. Cometeu mais um erro. A fila está ficando grande, e mais grave. Eu ajudo as pessoas, mas precisa ter critério, bom senso. O que é do site se resolve saqui. Fora daqui eu posso ajudar com outras coisas que não cabem aqui desde que caiba. Tentou se comunicar comigo pela porta dos fundos, sequer adotou o processo normal de aproximação com alguém em uma rede social.

> mas sou simplesmente ignorado.

Não foi ignorado, respondi educadamente, posso colar aqui.

> Isso me leva a crer que é
>   muito mais fácil ser ajudado do que tentar ajudar

É verdade, nem imagina como é difícil pra gente que faz isso o tempo todo, que damos atenção para os usuários novatos, na medida do que podemos, e olha a atenção que está recebendo.

> Aqui é mais fácil ser um sanguessuga?

Sim, sempre foi, com larga margem, e os novatos acham que a vida deles é difícil assim mesmo, sem nunca se colocar no lugar de quem faz este site ser um sucesso.

> Pra mim, é muito cômodo ficar de boa e continuar só sugando, pois se
>   eu for banido, o Google vai continuar trazendo as respostas

Para as pessoas que possuem carreiras bem sucedidas também podem se acomodar e curtir o que alcançaram sem se preocupar com quem ainda está aprendendo. E mais, deixar conteúdo ruim rolar solto sem critério algum.

> sinceramente, é muito desmotivante tentar ajudar por aqui.

Acredite é para todos em algum momento, para alguns o tempo todo, e cada tem que fazer sua parte. A gente ajuda muito com programação e outras coisas, até sobre política nos ajudamos no local adequado (ou nem tanto), ou nos ajudamos na diversão rolando memes como loucos, e podemos ajudar pessoas que tem outras dificuldades, mas [não tudo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51024481/i-am-quadriplegia-and-like-programming), não podemos ajudar quem não se importa com as regras, com a cultura, com o processo geral, com as normas sociais, etc. Se fosse uma coisa só seria mais fácil. Porém ainda podemos orientar um pouco. Podemos fazer isto até mesmo para quem contribui muito pouco. Note que você tem 1 pergunta e algumas respostas não muito bem recebidas. Acho que poderia refletir sobre isto. Aí pode ser que mude esta situação.

Sua contribuição na *tag* foi dizer que faltava aspas em um lugar, em uma pergunta que não estava clara se seria só isto. Me parece que saber que falava aspas não qualifica muito bem. E responder uma pergunta assim não pega muito bem na cultura do SOpt, o ideal seria esperar para ver se é isto mesmo. Algumas pessoas chamam isto se sanguessuga de reputação, que quer responder qualquer coisa só pra ganhar uns pontinhos. Não estou falando que é, mas passa essa impressão quando faz isto.

> é muito desmotivante tentar ajudar por aqui

Você nem imagina quanto, porque temos que adivinhar o que as pessoas estão perguntando, somos ignorados, xingados, atacados, temos um trabalhão por causa da preguiça de muitos, temos que fazer bastante pela completa desqualificação de outros tantos, temos que gastar um tempão explicando como o site funciona, como é a cultura daqui e mais um monte de coisa. Mas a gente faz. Mesmo não sendo pago, mesmo muitas vezes atrapalhando a vida profissional e pessoal, mesmo sequer recebendo uma aceitação ou votos das pessoas que se beneficiam do conteúdo gerado, que é o mínimo que quem participa espera. E muitos usuários nem se preocupam como isto muito perguntam e somem, outros andam pelo site, acham coisas pelo Google ou por aqui, se registram participam por anos e não dá nada em troca por tudo o que recebe, e o que se espera seria só a pessoa votar naquilo que é bom. As pessoas que aproveitam o conteúdo e não vota poderia ser chamada de sanguessuga? Isto é desmotivante. Mas é um direito das pessoas, o sistema privilegia sanguessugas

Está aqui há 2 anos e meio, quantos votos deu? 3? Acha que está colaborando? Acha que a sua vida é difícil aqui? Está vendo a dos outros?

> OBS: Não estou criticando a pessoa quem moderou a pergunta, muito
>   menos questionando seus titulos ou méritos, pois acredito que ela fez
>   por merecer, estou exemplificando o caso para demonstrar o quanto é
>   difícil ajudar.

Era só não citar isto que saberíamos que não está criticando nada disso. Mas citando...

Espero ter ajudado a ter uma atividade positiva aqui.

Sobre a pergunta específica já falaram bastante, ainda tem muitas coisas confusas e acho pouco provável que saiba o que ele quer, mas coloca a resposta aqui pra gente avaliar se realmente entendeu o que mais ninguém entendeu. Isto pode ser muito mais efetivo.

Answer (score 18):

Primeiro, acho que o termo que você escolheu ("sanguessuga") pode causar um pouco de confusão, já que, pelo que entendi, você usou com um significado diferente do que é comumente usado no site.

[Esta página do FAQ](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1160/112052) descreve o problema dos "vampiros de ajuda" (do inglês *Help Vampire*), que também pode ser traduzido como "sanguessuga".

De forma resumida, um sanguessuga é aquele que faz perguntas de qualquer jeito, sem se preocupar se ela está clara o suficiente, se faz sentido para os outros, se irrita quando pedem que esclareça os pontos duvidosos, e quer simplesmente que "resolvam meu problema agora, é URGENTE PLEASEEEE!".

E quando o sanguessuga consegue ajuda, não [marca a resposta como correta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer), não dá nenhum feedback dizendo se funcionou ou não, simplesmente some. Afinal, o problema dele foi resolvido, ele não se preocupa com os futuros visitantes do site que podem estar com o mesmo problema (que chegam aqui pelo Google, que nem você, eu, e todos nós fazemos).

Por isso que é importante fechar as perguntas dos sanguessugas o quanto antes, para que este comportamento não seja estimulado. Se olharmos por este ângulo, o fato do site ser fortemente moderado e ter regras rígidas para fechar perguntas desfavorece os sanguessugas.

---

Mas creio que você usou o termo no sentido de "alguém que só usa o site mas não contribui", ou seja, só acessa no modo "read-only" (que é o que a grande maioria faz: busca no google, acha um link do Stack Overflow e segue a vida).

Neste caso, concordo que estes são usuários privilegiados, pois têm à sua disposição um universo de conhecimento acumulado como nenhum outro site possui. E tudo de graça, escrito por outras pessoas que gastaram seu tempo naquilo.

Se você chama estes usuários read-only de sanguessugas, então podemos até dizer que o site os "privilegia". Afinal, conhecimento de qualidade, e grátis, precisa mais?

---

Quanto ao fato de ser burocrático, bem...

Para responder perguntas não há nenhuma restrição. Você até pode responder sem criar uma conta.

O que é difícil no começo, e pode inibir os novos usuários, são as regras rígidas. Ou pelo menos, mais rígidas do que a média dos outros sites. A maioria está acostumada com redes sociais, onde se pode escrever o que quiser sem filtros nem qualquer respeito à língua portuguesa e à coerência, e ao chegar em um site que não é assim, podem se assustar.

Para o bem e para o mal, é o que faz o nível do site ser superior à média, mesmo que isso afaste algumas pessoas que se assustam no início. É o preço a se pagar para manter o alto nível e não virar um yahoo respostas (o extremo oposto deste site, eu diria).

Quanto à pergunta que você mencionou, a [resposta do Jefferson](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/7139/112052) já mostra bem porque ela não é clara o suficiente para ser respondida, mesmo depois da edição feita. E na minha opinião, dificilmente será reaberta se continuar assim.

Comment: Eu pensei em mencionar os vampiros de ajuda e os _read-only_, mas me esqueci. Com sua resposta, nem preciso falar sobre eles, bastante linkar. Ótimas ponderações

Answer (score 16):

O que você considera ser sanguessuga? Por exemplo, não saber fazer um "hello, world" é ser sanguessuga? [Tipo isso](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/309210/64969)? Ou ser sanguessuga é postar perguntas no site e jamais responder perguntas de outrem? Mesmo que essas perguntas sejam relevantes para pessoas alheias à sua criação e resposta? Na minha visão, qualquer problema claramente sobre programação e que não foge ao escopo (nem é absurdamente amplo) merece estar aqui e ser respondida.

> A [excelente resposta do @hkotsubo](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/7140/64969) fala e define outros dois tipos de "sanguessugas" com maestria

Se você for ver, muitas pessoas acabam desistindo de perguntar, pois elas não sabem se expressar, elas não sabem nem qual é a sua dúvida real. Ou então [querem que façamos o seu trabalho](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5486/132). Isso é horrível de feio. Muitas vezes eu posto o e-mail de um amigo falando "peça orçamento para esse cara" (tenho o devido consentimento para fazer isso, já falei com ele a respeito).

Tem pessoas que não sabem minimamente o que é um texto bem redigido e tenta empurrar a dúvida de qualquer maneira. Essas pessoas mal comportadas normalmente recebem um baque de realidade quando chegam aqui. Querendo ou não, somos uma comunidade cuja estilística e estética textual tem um padrão razoável (eu diria médio/medíocre, mas normalmente tem uma conotação negativa essas palavras). Não se aceita aqui lixo, temos muitos usuários zelosos em manter a sala em ordem.

Às vezes, um ou outro se cansa de determinados usuários que, mesmo apontando "macho, aperta <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd> para formatar esse código, ômidideusu!" e simplesmente deixamos ele de lado. Já deixei de responder um usuário por conta do comportamento dele repetitivo de não formatar seu código (que mesmo formatado era difícil de ler e entender).

Então, nós não favorecemos quaisquer usuários. Ganha reputação aqui quem, ao ver da comunidade, agrega valor com perguntas/respostas boas/médias relevantes. Você não precisa ser um Maniero na hora de criar conteúdo, você precisa ser você mesmo. Se não o mundo seria homogeneizado e muito chato (tanto no sentido de "tedioso" como no sentido de "plano, sem profundidade"). Ser um aglomerado de diversas pessoas, com estilos e vivências diferentes, faz de qualquer comunidade estilo wiki-wiki crescer melhor e mais rápido.

Quando eu creio que uma pergunta é digna, vou correndo [tentar salvá-la](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6857/64969)  das maneiras que [acho que são as adequadas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/306086/erro-aritm%c3%a9tico-a-partir-de-20-casas-decimais-em-c-c#comment624069_306086) para cada situação.

---

A propósito, é bem capaz daquela pergunta ter salvação. Mas ela está vaga demais, não tem substância.

Para começar, o título: "Dúvida sobre classes"

Mais vago que isso creio que seria apenas "Dúvida". Esse é o primeiro impacto que um leitor e potencial respondedor terá. Em seguida:

> Estou com um problema onde não consigo entender como posso fazer para acessar um certo campo de uma determinada classe.

Essa é a introdução do texto. Depois disso temos o desenvolvimento e a conclusão. Temos aqui alguma ideia um pouco abstrata do que seja a questão, mas poderia ter colocado um pouco mais de ênfase. Ou então poderia tentar destrinchar melhor a apresentação do problema (vulgo "introdução do texto") em mais um ou dois parágrafos.

Depois disso, no desenvolvimento do texto:

> Não sei explicar bem como é essa estrutura onde estou fazendo a leitura, mas tenho um codigo exemplo, como mencionado abaixo:

É, se você não sabe explicar sua dúvida (que depende da estrutura), então fica difícil conseguirem explicar. Depois temos um trecho de código e a finalização da conclusão:

> Infelizmente, não posso efetuar mudanças nesse código, pois esse trecho é utilizado na geração de um XML envolvendo herança de classe.

Ok, esse parágrafo realmente está em perfeito tom com a estrutura textual. O autor colocou aqui um ponto de limitação extra, que realmente não era necessário comentar na introdução. Também não ficaria elegante comentar em outro canto do desenvolvimento do texto, ele manteve-se fiel ao papel de transmissão de mensagem.

Em seguida, temos a conclusão:

> Como eu conseguiria acessar essa propriedade?

Aqui temos um problema de referência. "Essa" é uma palavra de referência anafórica, faz referência a algo já dito anteriormente no texto. Em linguagem coloquial se permite fazer uma referência catafórica, substituindo a palavra formal adequada "esta". Mesmo assim, do texto, não consigo discernir qual propriedade ele quer acessar. Também não diz em elementos textuais quem é ela, portanto falha na catáfora também.

Depois da conclusão, há um elemento extra-textual que se assemelha a uma nota de rodapé:

> EDIT: Se eu tento acessar a propriedade *carro.Tipo.Placa* em debug, eu consigo, pois a variável carro tem seu tipo como **Sedan**. Mas se tento incluir essa linha no código ele não permite a compilação, pois a variável carro tem seu tipo como **Carro** ainda.

Essa observação parece estar totalmente deslocada de contexto, ela faz parte no desenvolvimento do problema. Apesar de que eu *não entendi* a intenção do autor em falar isso, nem o seu significado na pergunta como o todo, sei que isso é algo que faz parte do problema, que não deveria ter sido deixado para um elemento fora do texto.

Comment: Eu acho que ele falou em sanguessugas meio trazendo da terminologia de trackers de torrent, onde quem só baixa é *leecher*. Só perguntar e não retribuir respondendo seria isso, na visão dele. Sua resposta é excelente pra ajudá-lo a entender os problemas da pergunta e sacar melhor como funciona o site. Parece ser um caso de alguém que quer participar mas está inseguro ou afoito. Coisa que passa com o tempo, acostumando com o site.

Comment: @bfavaretto essa do torrent não sabia, então eu sou um *leecher* rsrs ... E qual a tradução para esta palavra ?

Comment: @NoobSaibot sanguessuga =] ou sanguessugador, já que termina em -er #hue

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado kkkk o nome já diz: Noob rs

Comment: Ser sanguessuga depende muito do prisma que você está olhando...
Um cara que só pergunta e não ajuda é um sanguessuga, mas um cara que se aproveita das respostas e sequer agradece ou vota também é um sanguessuga...

Comment: @NoobSaibot Como disse o Jefferson, *leech* é sanguessuga (o bicho), *leecher* é gíria (ou termo técnico?) de bittorrent. Na verdade o modo como o protocolo bittorrent funciona depende das pessoas não serem *leechers*. Os trackers mais sérios (geralmente fechados, com acesso por convite)  banem quem baixa mais do que "upa". Geralmente exigem que você suba `x` vezes o que baixa, sendo `x > 1` geralmente.

Comment: @EduardoOliveira Aqui no site pode só perguntar sem ser sanguessuga. Tem gente que sabe perguntar muito bem. E sem boas perguntas o site não existe.

Comment: My Gosh....o problema não está em perguntar e sim em responder....

Comment: @EduardoOliveira ainda não entendo o problema que esta enfrentando. Eu sou um cara que não sou formado, nem curso, muito menos trabalho na área de programação. Mas sou muito curioso e sempre gostei de códigos, aprendi muito fuçando, e estou aprendendo muito aqui na **comunidade**. Existem varias perguntas, e até eu mesmo dou preferência de fechar uma pergunta caso seja necessário, do que responde-lá, ainda mais quando se trata de um erro de digitação. Mas você deveria fazer o [tour] para entender o funcionamento da **comunidade** e acessar a [help] para mais.

Comment: @EduardoOliveira Eu entendi o que você está dizendo, eu sei que é sobre responder. Só estava respondendo ao comentário onde você disse que quem só pergunta seria sanguessuga. Não necessariamente. Mas eu entendo o debate que você quer trazer. Você disse: "é muito desmotivante tentar ajudar por aqui". Não é o primeiro a dizer isso nem será o último. A comunidade tem o que mudar pra melhorar isso? Tem. A ferramenta também tem. Mesmo assim, muito do que frustra quem tenta contribuir e não consegue tende a passar conforme a pessoa vai acostumando com o site. Continue participando, é o meu conselho.

Answer (score 10):

> Aqui é mais fácil ser um sanguessuga?

Claro que se o acesso às respostas não for barrado por uma "paywall" ou por requisitos de reputação, vai ser sempre mais fácil ler só do que contribuir.

Mas, para responder melhor ao fulcral da pergunta: **o SO é um site que não faz um trabalho bom o suficiente a encorajar os utilizadores a voltarem depois de obterem as respostas para os seus problemas**. Tudo bem que como algumas respostas aqui indicaram, há o termo historicamente usado de "help vampire" pare designar os utilizadores que nem para votar nas respostas às suas perguntas voltam; mas, esse caso à parte, a culpa não é da maior parte dos utilizadores mas antes do sistema, e nós **estamos a trabalhar em maneiras de tentar incentivar os utilizadores a voltarem e tirarem mais prazer de ajudar os outros.**

Comment: É fato. Recentemente me deparei com algumas perguntas que fiz no SOen e percebi que não havia votado nas respostas e nem escolhido uma correta. Uma delas era de 2014. Certo que nunca é tarde demais, mas realmente já havia deixado de lado por não frequentar a comunidade.

Comment: Espero que desta vez seja verdade, todo mundo está cansando de ouvi falar em mudanças que não ocorrem nunca. Sim, ocorrem mudanças, mas que não resolvem nada. Na verdade estamos vendo algumas coisas que vão afastar mais ainda pessoas que contribuem. A ideia de que o sistema deve interferir pouco não deu certo. As pessoas precisam de interação, e a majoria parte precisa ser automatizada total ou parcialmente, deixando para as pessoas decidirem só o que precisa mesmo, tirando um frado grande que cansa. Alguns casos não tem salvação, já foio tempo de ser o oposto do site de troca de sexo s/ hífen

Answer (score -6):

Eu entrei há pouco tempo como contribuidor realmente do SO. Tinha experiência como perguntador no Math Exchange, porém.

Quanto a responder as perguntas por aqui, prefiro aquelas que tenham dúvidas muito específicas porque, toda vez que tentei contribuir em perguntas abertas, fui simplesmente *rechaçado*, talvez por não ter bastante pontinhos, como outras pessoas que sempre vejo respondendo - e ganhando - pontinhos por aqui. Ou talvez porque eu não seja conhecedor dos jargões técnicos e frufrus semânticos que as pessoas da área de TI *aprendem a gostar*, durante a formação.

Eu acho que *sanguessugas* sempre vão existir, porque eles também existem no mundo real, apesar de serem menos evidentes - a Internet expõe mais claramente ao público quem é quem por dentro, do que a vida real.

Sempre que puder, Eduardo, responda às perguntas. Sempre que quiser contribuir, contribua, mesmo desconhecendo a verdadeira face do PO. Porque o avanço da sociedade como um todo depende da colaboração entre as pessoas que fazem parte dela, e todos nós, *sanguessugas* ou pessoas de bem, fazemos parte dela.

Às vezes, as pessoas acham que devem ser retribuídas de alguma forma com as respostas que dão. Se você acha isso, então não contribua mais, porque isso não serve para você.

Comment: Um ponto negativo nas suas respostas (peguei o barco andando, fiquei um tempo inativo no site, e não acompanhei muito o seu caso, mas mesmo assim pude notar) é que a maioria das suas respostas são secas, não possuem uma explicação do que fez e como chegou a solução, isso é visto por muitos como resposta "suporte técnico", onde não há uma real intenção de ensinar(acredito que esta é a maior motivação da rede SOpt), e sim de solucionar o problema.