# Podemos fazer perguntas e respondê-las afim de passar conhecimento?

Tags: suporte, perguntas, respostas

Podemos fazer perguntas para respondê-las com o objetivo de transferir conhecimento a qualquer pessoa que busque sobre um determinado assunto? Por exemplo: tenho um código pronto para enviar e-mail para o cliente e o proprietário pelo PHPMailer incluso o HTML só pro cara colocar o que quiser lá dentro. A única coisa a fazer é trocar os dados de autenticação do e-mail que dispara.

Esse tipo de conteúdo é de grande ajuda para desenvolvedores e programadores. Podemos postar e responder como usar por exemplo?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sim, e isso inclusive [é incentivado](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/422/responder-sua-pr%C3%B3pria-pergunta?lq=1). Porém antes verifique o seguinte:

- Pesquise no site antes e veja se a pergunta já existe. No caso do seu exemplo de envio de email, talvez baste postar uma nova resposta em [Como enviar e-mail com PHP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/23602/como-enviar-e-mail-com-php)
- Atenha-se ao formato de perguntas e respostas do site: poste uma pergunta com cara de pergunta, e uma resposta com cara de resposta. Ajuda se você fingir que está respondendo para outra pessoa.

Comment: Ver também: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/410/por-que-existe-preconceito-em-perguntar-e-responder-a-pr%C3%B3pria-pergunta?lq=1 e http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/37/respondi-minha-pr%C3%B3pria-pergunta-fiz-algo-errado. Talvez esta sua pergunta acabe marcada como duplicata de uma das 3 discussões já existentes.