# Devo deixar de fazer uma pergunta por ela já ter respostas em outro site?

Tags: debate

Mais cedo tive uma interação com outro membro da comunidade acerca de uma pergunta que publiquei.

[Converter arquivos .docx para .pdf com Python 3](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/561494/converter-arquivo-docx-para-pdf-com-python-3)

Há alguns dias tenho lido discussões como [essa](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4432/%c3%89-errado-perguntar-por-coisas-que-se-acham-facilmente-como-alguns-julgam-no-go), [essa](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2170/quest%c3%a3o-simples-demais-feita-por-um-experiente) e [essa aqui](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1845/podemos-fazer-perguntas-e-respond%c3%aa-las-afim-de-passar-conhecimento?noredirect=1&lq=1). Das opiniões expostas nas discussões mencionadas, extraí (quotando frases retiradas de respostas e comentários) o seguinte:

- [Não é errado postar perguntas simples. As respostas devem ser encontradas em algum lugar, e o objetivo é que o SOpt seja este lugar](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/300325)
- [Alguns usuários fazem perguntas para introduzir conhecimento relevante ao site.](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2171/300325)
- [A ideia é construir um repositório de perguntas e respostas úteis](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2170/quest%c3%a3o-simples-demais-feita-por-um-experiente#comment6902_2171)

Sabendo disso, resolvi fazer minha pergunta. Pesquisei aqui no SOpt e não encontrei a resposta. Quando encontrei esse desafio (há alguns meses), achei extremamente difícil encontrar respostas em português, mas encontrei tudo o que procurava no [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6011115/doc-to-pdf-using-python) (note as views, votos, a discussão, etc.).

Aqui no SOpt, encontrei perguntas relacionadas utilizando as linguagens [C#](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/316400/convertendo-arquivo-word-para-pdf), [PHP e JS](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/304024/converter-um-documento-worddoc-docx-para-pfd-usando-php-ou-javascript) além de [uma pergunta sobre Python](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/245723/converter-documento-worddoc-para-pdf-usando-python) (que foi o AP pedindo ajuda para entender o código, nada mais). Nenhuma dessas perguntas está negativada.

Os materiais que mencionei são todos antigos, mas mesmo hoje **a resposta para essa pergunta não é de fácil acesso aos falantes de português**.

Minha pergunta (e resposta) foram duramente negativadas, mesmo trazendo pra essa comunidade conteúdo RELEVANTE (quem trabalha com automação entende o quão útil é a informação) que não estava disponível em português. Não estou aqui pra contestar os votos, cada um vota como quer. Talvez minha pergunta esteja mal feita, mal formulada, seja irrelevante, preguiçosa, etc. Tudo bem, só peço que me avisem para que eu possa melhorá-la e ajudar a comunidade.

Foi levantado nos comentários da pergunta o seguinte ponto: É possível que minha pergunta estivesse sendo negativada por que "hoje já existe o Github com as respostas" (parafraseando bem porcamente [este comentário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/561494/converter-arquivo-docx-para-pdf-com-python-3#comment994497_561494). de forma alguma quero tirar o argumento do contexto).

Esse é o ponto que quero discutir. O "já haver respostas em outro site" (GitHub) é um motivo válido pra não postarmos aqui? Essa regra vale pra todo tipo de pergunta? E, se não vale, a quais perguntas em específico essa regra se aplica?

Comment: Olhando a resposta agora, não estou falando exatamente da pergunta, o código que citou em sua resposta também é sobre linha de comando, mesmo que você tenha colocado dentro de um python, então não foi python que resolveu de fato, se a pergunta fosse algo como "como usar linha de comando dentro de python?" ou "como executar um comando externo em python?" talvez fosse uma boa resposta (claro que não focando na parte de PDF). Então me parece que o problema da pergunta na verdade foi a intenção da resposta, que não é uma boa solução, a pergunta em si não agrega uma base de conhecimento

Comment: Da forma que foi formulada ficou mesmo como um "repositório de código", então o comentário do Augusto me parece pertinente, creio que talvez você não tenha entendido o que ele quis lhe orientar, não é o problema de existir ou não github, o problema é que de fato da forma que foi feita não está agregando algo a base de conhecimento do site, está apenas fornecendo um código que se resume a copiar e colar para uso e ainda dependerá de ferramentas de terceiros (LibreOffice).

Comment: Se a pergunta fosse no https://superuser.com/ focado em como usar comando de linha do LibreOffice para converter DOCX para PDF seria uma pergunta útil ao site (ao superuser), para o Stack Overflow em Português recomendo que as perguntas sejam focadas no escopo [help/on-topic]

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento tudo bem. Mas de qual maneira a minha resposta difere das repostas dadas às outras perguntas que linkei? Sobre o ponto de ser "sobre linha de comando" e por isso "pertencer ao SU", não sei até que ponto essa definição se encaixa. Rodar um comando da CLI dentro do contexto de um script ainda é um problema específico do Python. Ainda mais se considerarmos que não existe SuperUser em português. Se eu fosse postar lá, me mandariam pro StackOverflow (onde a pergunta já existe).

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento entendo que a pergunta pode acabar fugindo do escopo do SOpt (não na minha opinião), mas dessa maneira a pergunta cai num limbo. Não pertence ao SOpt por que usa linha de comando. Não pertence ao SU por que é de programação. Já existe no SOen. OK, vai existir só em inglês.

Comment: A pergunta de C# focou focada no Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word, mesmo não sendo uma grandiosa postagem, ali o contexto provavelmente foi bem aceito pela comunidade (os usuários que participaram votando), porque era para resolver dentro do que existe nativo no .NET (como você pode observar https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.word?view=word-pia)

Comment: A de PHP (com a minha resposta) é o aquela situação, outros tempos (como o Augusto  já lhe orientou), no caso na época eu nem deveria ter respondido, deveria ser apenas um comentário, porque ali é mais indicação de software que qualquer outra coisa.

Comment: Sobre a pergunta do SOen, é preciso entender que não somos o [stackoverflow.com](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1/3635), apesar de abordamos um escopo semelhante, aqui temos alguns parâmetros próprios, o que já foi muito debatido no [META](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/). Fora que se fosse até uma tentativa de responder ajudando alguém daria para entender, poderia ser feito até em um comentário, mas não é o caso, ali você tentou trazer algo que a solução não esta na linguagem, mas sim em terceiros, mesmo que tenha usado o "contexto" do Python, a solução não está contextualizada nele

Comment: Devo ressaltar que o problema ali não é se a pergunta é simples ou não, a questão é que entendemos que tentou trazer algo que achou interessante, mas hoje temos um escopo próprio melhor definido e focado em tornar o site uma base de conhecimento, e é esse o ponto que o Augusto aparentemente tentou lhe orientar.

Answer (score 3):

## Pergunta:

Devo deixar de fazer uma pergunta por ela já ter respostas em outro site?

## Resposta:

Se for **só por isso**, não deve deixar de perguntar.

A pergunta ou dúvida (ou respectiva solução) existir em outro site é irrelevante para os critérios do site, desde que não infringido nenhum direito sobre o conteúdo original.

### Mas...

... é bom levar em consideração algumas coisas, pois os negativos na postagem não parecem ter sido por isso, nem consigo ver uma relação direta.

Invertendo a pergunta:

- P: Quais perguntas não devem ter feitas no SOpt?
- R: As que não se encaixam no escopo do site definido na [Central de Ajuda](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help).

Mas se faltar detalhamento na página de escopo do site, tem a "versão explicada" aqui:

[O que é o Stack Overflow](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7256/70)

Sobre o resto do texto, não adianta entrar muito em detalhes, pois o voto da comunidade já deixou claro que, em que pese o autor achar que é uma boa postagem, a comunidade entendeu de outra forma e expressou via voto. Se algum dos votantes quiser, pode complementar com uma explicação, mas é opcional.

#### Sobre negativos e fechamentos:

No meu entendimento a pergunta poderia até ser fechada pelas razões já explicadas nesse mesmo link (lembrando que isso não é banimento da pergunta, apenas um pedido de melhoria para esclarecer qual a dificuldade do problema enfrentado de fato - isso já é uma dica).

No caso, eu não o faria de imediato unilateralmente por estar com a discussão iniciada aqui, mas se/em ocorrendo, eventuais explicações, se necessário, seriam dadas no próprio quadro de fechamento ou comentários de lá, não estenderia nessa discussão.

A pergunta central é sobre "existir em outro site" e já foi respondida, mas como o modelo da rede é "um problema específico por postagem", se ainda restarem dúvidas pode comentar ou elaborar melhor nas postagens específicas já existentes sobre cada tema. Pode usar a [busca do Meta](/search), mas já vou adiantar alguns links que acredito relevantes:

- [Guia de sobrevivência (resumido) do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8089)
- [Visão geral do funcionamento do sistema](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour)
- [Guia rápido sobre como fazer perguntas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
- [Assuntos e tipos de perguntas permitidos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
- [FAQ da comunidade](/q/699)
- [Questões de linha de comando podem ser aceitas?](/q/2471)
- [Super User em Português - Já era no Area 51](/q/2482)

Mas não se limite a estes. O quadro de fechamentos tem outras postagens sobre trazer conteúdo de fora, e o Meta tem discussões extensas sobre os principais assuntos que podem justificar os negativos dados.

O importante é que cada tema seja debatido em sua postagem específica.