# Essa pergunta pode ser reaberta?

Tags: debate, pergunta-específica

A pergunta [Como configurar a segurança para servidores dedicados e VPS?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/68071/dicas-de-seguran%C3%A7a-para-dedicado-ou-vps?noredirect=1#comment147061_68071) foi fechada por mim e alguns colegas como não é claro o que está perguntando.

De fato na [primeira edição](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/revisions/68071/1) não existe uma pergunta em si. Nas edições seguintes ela foi dividida em uma [pergunta com resposta do próprio autor](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/422/responder-sua-pr%C3%B3pria-pergunta).

Mesmo assim acho que a pergunta precisa de algo mais. A questão central do que a pergunta quer resolver não está clara para mim e os passos recomendados na resposta não são explicados (por exemplo, o que é um CMQ ou CMC?).

O que acham da [pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/revisions/68071/3) e a [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/68074/4751) no estado atual? Existe algo que vocês veem que precisa ser melhorado para reabrir a pergunta?

Comment: Se você lê com atenção, verá que não é uma pergunta, e sim uma contribuição.

Comment: Acho que seria mais apropriado que [esta pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/68071/dicas-de-seguran%C3%A7a-para-dedicado-ou-vps) fosse um [wiki-da-comunidade](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/community-wiki).

Comment: @Tiago este site é um site de perguntas e repostas, se quer contribuir com conhecimento pode responder a questões. Se quer fazer perguntas e responder as mesmas pode-o fazer. Mas tem de ser pergunta e resposta separada. A sua pergunta como está não é clara o suficiente para que se possa responder. Para que outros possam responder e para quem tiver o mesmo problema chegar lá.

Comment: Só lembrando que o wiki não confere de pontos de reputação (o que é errado a meu ver, mas não vem ao caso agora...). [Mais sobre o wiki da comunidade](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts) (em inglês).

Comment: @Tiago, como o Jorge disse. Responder sua própria pergunta é bem vindo por aqui, porém o problema é o formato atual da pergunta que precisa ser melhorada.

Comment: Apesar de eu também não saber o que é CMQ, CMC ou PQP, acho que a pergunta pode ser facilmente editada (porque tem sim problemas de clareza) e reaberta.

Comment: Alguem escreve aqui como deveria ser então, porque eu não sei ser mais claro, desculpe mas é a verdade. **Dicas de segurança para Dedicado ou VPS** `Tutorial completo (pelo menos a intenção é que seja) sobre configuração de segurança de VPS/DEDICADOS. Trata-se de um passo-a-passo bem explicado sobre cada configuração.`

Comment: @Tiago Este é um site de **perguntas e respostas**, portanto o texto precisa ser uma pergunta, e não uma descrição do que vem abaixo como resposta.

Comment: @Tiago talvez se voçê mudasse o titulo para `Como configurar a segurança para DEDICADO e VPS?`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Acredito que mudando a pergunta ela pode ser reaberta. Por exemplo, poderia alterar o titulo para ser uma pergunta, e na descrição demonstrar o problema que estava tendo. A questão poderia ser algo assim:

---

**Como configurar a segurança para DEDICADO e VPS?**

Estou tendo problemas com as configuraçãos de segurança de VPS/DEDICADOS, como fazer essa configuração?

---

Realmente nem sei sobre o que se trata esse assunto, mas acho que essa seria uma forma de resolver.

**EDIT**

Acabei de editar a questão, assim que aprovarem a edição (Se analisarem condizente) e alguma boa alma quiser abrir votação para reabrir a pergunta, fique a vontade.

Comment: Concordo totalmente, inclusive eu tinha comentado isso ali em cima pra ver se alguém se animava e resolvia o problema, mas ninguém fez nada... Esse é o tipo de coisa que qualquer um pode consertar no site, e quem fizer ajuda muito a comunidade.

Comment: Sempre fico em dúvida, se posso alterar a pergunta a esse nível.

Comment: Manda ver, isso salva a pergunta do fechamento ;)

Comment: Editei mais um pouco em cima, com base na resposta (presumindo que ali estão as intenções do autor) e reabri. Enxergo um risco de ainda acharem a pergunta ampla demais e fecharem novamente, por isso na minha edição tentei especificar um pouco mais a pergunta.

Comment: Também fiquei com essa percepção de que pudesse estar um pouco ampla, mas agora acredito que esteja legal.