# Responder a própria pergunta

Tags: debate, perguntas, respostas, perguntas-fechadas

Sou membro com atividade recente. Li as regras e dicas de como perguntar e responder.

Quero saber porquê minha pergunta com resposta foi fechada: [Disparar e-mail com anexo Excel.](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/339941/disparar-e-mails-com-anexo-no-excel) (não é uma reclamação, quero saber para melhorar minhas perguntas futuramente.)

Sobre minha pergunta: Eu estava com esta necessidade e não encontrei resposta aqui no site. Buscando na internet obtive uma solução interessante e quis postar aqui para ajudar outras pessoas com a mesma necessidade.

Antes de fazer essa pergunta, eu li esta: [Responder sua própria pergunta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/422/responder-sua-pr%C3%B3pria-pergunta)

Comment: Quando uma pergunta é fechada, aparece abaixo dela um box amarelo com alguns links, como a página **[ask]** e a [Central de Ajuda](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions). Sugiro que leia estes links para entender melhor o tipo de perguntas que são adequadas ao modelo do site. Leia também [este outro link da central de ajuda](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), o [Manual de como não fazer perguntas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5483/112052) e [O que é o Stack Overflow](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7256/112052)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Uma coisa é fazer uma pergunta que todos podem responder e você responder. Outra bem diferente é fazer uma pergunta que não pode ser respondida por qualquer pessoa que não seja você. Se você não tivesse respondido ela ninguém poderia responder e ela seria fechada como ampla porque não tem um problema específico ali, não se sabe exatamente o que é o problema, dá margem para várias interpretações e respostas muito díspares poderiam ser postadas e qualquer uma poderia estar certa, ou nenhuma acertaria porque só o autor da pergunta sabe o que seria o certo. A perguntaria seria fechada imediatamente se não tivesse uma resposta, talvez até como fora de escopo por estar pedindo para fazer tudo para você. Dá para alegar que ela não está clara, mas ainda seria fechada. Ninguém mais poderia dar uma resposta ali, por isso ela foi fechada.

A pergunta não é boa e não atende o critério mínimo para permanecer aberta. Ela foi postada com o **único** propósito postar uma solução. Isto funciona para algo mais contido, para algo conceitual, mas para algo aberto desta forma não. Se a pergunta fosse boa, desse todos os detalhes, fosse específica, desse a oportunidade de outras pessoas responderem também, aí estaria ok.

O Stack Overflow não é um repositório de soluções individuais é de soluções gerais para todos. Na forma atual a resposta atende sua necessidade, mas ninguém sabe qual é ela lendo a pergunta. Lendo a resposta talvez dê para saber, mas é só a sua necessidade.